# Ubuntu 13.04 Asus N56 keyboard brightness restarting

Tags: keyboard, brightness, asus

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on my Asus N56 notebook. Everything works perfect except keyboard brightness. Every time my notebook starts with the keyboard backlit set to the max value. I'd like to change it - keyboard backlit set default to disable.

I've tried add this line in `etc/rc.local`:

`echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness`

Unfortunately it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a delay before the echo command line, like this:

```
sleep 7

echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

That should change the timing so that all appropriate software components are running before the command is to be executed. Depending on your configuration you can decrease the time value; just make a few iterations in order to determine the shortest delay that will work reliably with your system.

Comment: Hi,I update ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 and keyboard backlight doesn't work (12.10 it work) and I don't have file into path /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness. Maybe I should install some driver?